# Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I am trying to duplicate a view and modify it, but it is giving me an error.

Before this, I did it with other views and it worked perfectly, all I had to do was rename the views and modify the code.

But now , I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in D:\UniServerZ\vhosts\restaurant\administrator\components\com_restaurant\views\reviews\view.html.php on line 54
```

Line 54 has this code:

```
$canDo = RestaurantHelper::getActions($state->get('filter.category_id'));
```

`var_dump($this)`; gives me the following ->

```
    object(RestaurantViewReviews)#156 (18) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["pagination":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["state":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_name":protected]=>
  string(7) "reviews"
  ["_models":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_basePath":protected]=>
  string(71) "D:\UniServerZ\vhosts\restaurant\administrator/components/com_restaurant"
  ["_defaultModel":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_layout":protected]=>
  string(7) "default"
  ["_layoutExt":protected]=>
  string(3) "php"
  ["_layoutTemplate":protected]=>
  string(1) "_"
  ["_path":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["template"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(89) "D:\UniServerZ\vhosts\restaurant\administrator\templates\isis\html\com_restaurant\reviews\"
      [1]=>
      string(91) "D:\UniServerZ\vhosts\restaurant\administrator\components\com_restaurant\views\reviews\tmpl\"
    }
    ["helper"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(80) "D:\UniServerZ\vhosts\restaurant\administrator\components\com_restaurant\helpers\"
    }
  }
  ["_template":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_output":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_escape":protected]=>
  string(16) "htmlspecialchars"
  ["_charset":protected]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["_errors":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["baseurl"]=>
  string(14) "/administrator"
  ["document"]=>
  object(JDocumentHTML)#122 (32) {
    ["_links"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_custom"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["template"]=>
    NULL
    ["baseurl"]=>
    NULL
    ["params"]=>
    NULL
    ["_file"]=>
    NULL
    ["_template":protected]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["_template_tags":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_caching":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_html5":"JDocumentHTML":private]=>
    NULL
    ["title"]=>
    string(27) "Restaurant - Administration"
    ["description"]=>
    string(24) "Restaurant description.."
    ["link"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["base"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["language"]=>
    string(5) "en-gb"
    ["direction"]=>
    string(3) "ltr"
    ["_generator"]=>
    string(40) "Joomla! - Open Source Content Management"
    ["_mdate"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["_tab"]=>
    string(2) "  "
    ["_lineEnd"]=>
    string(1) "
"
    ["_charset"]=>
    string(5) "utf-8"
    ["_mime"]=>
    string(9) "text/html"
    ["_namespace"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["_profile"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["_scripts"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_script"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_styleSheets"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_style"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_metaTags"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["http-equiv"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["content-type"]=>
        string(24) "text/html; charset=utf-8"
      }
      ["standard"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["keywords"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["_engine"]=>
    NULL
    ["_type"]=>
    string(4) "html"
    ["mediaVersion":protected]=>
    string(32) "5a22c74e31c4742e55ee891853d099a2"
  }
}
```

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$state` is not an object. That means that it is not correctly initialized earlier in your method. Or may be it should be `$this->state` instead of `$state`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. I have this code before that line:  $state = $this->get('State'); So basically I am already calling the object's get() method and assigning to the $state variable. But this doesn't seem to work in this case. Hmm, any more ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Then something is wrong in your code. May be model is not connected with the view and you can not get the state from it. Try to dump `$state` or `$this` to check whether the model is ok. Then try to explore further where the problem could be.

Comment: var_dump($state) gives me "NULL". while var_dump($this) 's output is too long to post here, so I added it to the original question. The model array seems is empty, is that the cause? Thanks

Comment: Yeah `_defaultModel` also is empty! Then you should go up to reviews controller and check there `display()` method. Is it custom? How do you instantiate the view there?

Comment: Well yes, I am creating the component myself. So yes I do have a 'RestaurantControllerReviews' controller with just a `getModel()` method in it. I have a generic `display()` method on my controller.php.

Comment: Strange. If you use a generic method it should pass the model automatically... May be your Model have incorrect class name?

Comment: Indeed. The getModel() method is not being used by Joomla, instead it is using the model after the view's name, even if I am explicitly declaring the getModel() method on the controller like this: `public function getModel($name = 'menu', $prefix = 'RestaurantModels')
 {
  $model = parent::getModel($name, $prefix, array('ignore_request' => true));
  return $model;
 }` , anyways thanks for the eye opener. I did make a model for reviews and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot! :)